# Querying Tableau Server dashboard from Excel

Tags: sql, excel, tableau-api

I'm trying to setup a query to a tableau server from MS Excel 2016 for the purpose of getting the data automatically out of tableau massaging it and emailing it out - I can do all of this relatively simple, HOWEVER, I have no clue how to setup the query to the tableau dashboard from Excel 2016.

Any advice would be highly appreciated I'm not certain even where to start and online searching has only netted me querying excel files from tableau, not the other way around

Comment: When you start Tableau Desktop, start by choosing your SQL DB in the left hand side pane of the window. Enter your credentials and choose the DB you want to connect. This will show you all the tables in that DB on the left hand side. You can either choose the tables you need or at the bottom of the list, there is an option to enter custom SQL. That way you can query as you need it.

Comment: Replicating the data used by Tableau in an excel file seems like a very inefficient way to use Tableau. Could you not recreate tables in Tableau containing the data? Or export the relevant data from Tableau using the Worksheet:Export menu?

Comment: I'm trying to do the query to sort of automate the export - I need to run some formulas and conditional formattingand send a formatted HTML email which I can can do through VBA but not tableau.

Comment: Accountants want to look at data behind the visuals for their own business needs.  Power BI offers this feature because it's a really useful feature for business users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-connect-power-bi-datasets-excel